# How to implements tablePerHierarchy with disciminator in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a class hirarchy :

```
class Item {}
class Participation extends Item{}
class Contribution extends Participation{}
class Question extends Participation{}
```

I would like to have a table per class so, I add tablePerHierarchy false in Item

I need a discrimator to implements a query : where class = "Contribution"

I try a lot of implementation but it's not working.

How to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you find any solution on this? I have exactly the same problem, and ataylor's answer is not doing what I need.

Answer (score 7):

Do you want table per hierarchy or table per class?  It's not clear in your question.

With the following domain objects, you can do it either way:

```
// Item.groovy
class Item {
    String x
}

// Participation.groovy
class Participation extends Item {                   
     String y
}
```

Using the default, table per hierarchy strategy, just one table will be used to store Items and all the subclasses of Items too.  The default discriminator column is called `class`, which grails will use automatically.  The schema generated by `grails schema-export` looks like this:

```
create table item (
    id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), 
    version bigint not null, 
    x varchar(255) not null,
    class varchar(255) not null,
    y varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
);
```

There's just one table for both classes which contains all the fields declared in every class in the hierarchy plus the discriminator column `class`.  If you do a query like `Participation.list()`, the SQL grails generates looks like this:

```
select
    this_.id as id1_0_,
    this_.version as version1_0_,
    this_.x as x1_0_,
    this_.y as y1_0_
from
    item this_
where
    this_.class='Participation'
```

By changing the inheritance strategy to table per class with `static mapping { tablePerHieracrchy false }` in Item.groovy, grails will generate a table for each of classes in the hierarchy.  Each table stores only the fields declared in each class, so a Participation object would be represented by a row in both the Item table and the Participation table.  The schema looks like this:

```
create table item (
    id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    version bigint not null,
    x varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table participation (
    id bigint not null,
    y varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

And the SQL for `Participation.list()` changes to:

```
select
    this_.id as id1_0_,
    this_1_.version as version1_0_,
    this_1_.x as x1_0_,
    this_.y as y2_0_
from
    participation this_
inner join
    item this_1_
        on this_.id=this_1_.id
```

Comment: With class Participation extends Item, I tried and it's clear but my question is more on the next inheritance 'Contribution extends Participation' and 'Question extends Participation'. The compiler request a discriminator on Question and only on question not on contribution.

Comment: atayar could you take a look at my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523408/how-to-make-tableperhierarchy-false-and-use-discriminator