# how to make tablePerHierarchy false and use discriminator?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, table-per-hierarchy, discriminator

A question like what I need is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192375/how-to-implements-tableperhierarchy-with-disciminator-in-grails) but it's answer is not satisfying what I need. I have classes like this :

```
abstract class A{
   String a
}
class B extends A{
   String b
}
class C extends A{
   String c
}
```

I want to have a table for each class, so I add tablePerHierarchy and set it false like this:

```
abstract class A{
   String a
   static mapping = {
       tablePerHierarchy false
   }
}
```

but when I run the program and it creates a database there are no discriminator, and I want to query table A and find out if it is B, or C? How Could I add discriminator to this strategy?

Comment: This maybe helpful `http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceInGORM`

Comment: @wwarlock thanks, but I've already look there and its not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported based on the [bug report](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5208).

Comment: Thanks, although it is an old post, and I'm currently not working on grails, but it is a good reference for others in future :)